# AsyncTask not keeping Object quick enough?

Tags: android, multithreading, reference, android-asynctask

I am basically starting an AsyncTask by pushing several intents into it

```
for (int key:mappedKeys){
  fireIntent.putExtra(LEDIntentService.keyID, key);
  new AsyncStartService().execute(fireIntent);
}
```

But the problem is that `keyID` of the Intent is not always the one it was when `execute()` was called.
Cloning the Intent before firing it fixes it but also slows it down.
Using `mappedKeys` inside the Task or a Runnable is no alternative for me.
Is this behaviour of AsyncTask intended?

```
protected class AsyncStartService extends AsyncTask<Intent,Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Intent... params) {
        for (int i = 0, paramsLength = params.length; i < paramsLength; i++) {
            Intent param = params[i];
            startService(param);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

There is more code to it, but this minimal fragment doesn't work.
It seems as if the foreach is done before the first param is enqued and then all items have the same value for `keyID`.

Comment: what you are trying to do?

Comment: This is a stab in the dark, but can't you put the contents of the for loop in a synchronized block?

Comment: Initialize a new Intent on every for loop step, u are changing the key value of that object in every loop step.

Comment: yeah, that was what I meant with cloning, I have now used a "dirty" casting method to get more than one param object type passed to the Task, but I am not really happy with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you startService in the AsyncTask?

From you code the foreach loop will not wait for the AsyncTask's doInBackground because it is not on the same thread, you need to create a new intent for each AsyncTask.

Comment: yeah, it seems as if, but why would I need to pass a reference then instead of accessing the intend directly, I though the AsyncTask would keep a copy on its own, which is why he needed the class reference. the `params` queue would not make much sense otherwise. Working around this is no real issue, I am using a single unhandled thread now, but it seems to deafeat much of the "usefulness" of AsyncTaks in my view.